# Video upload in MVC application?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, video, upload

I want to upload video in my mvc application please tell me how will I do that and what necessary steps I shall follow.

I am a naive user to the mvc applications

Thanks
Ritz

Comment: Have a look to this www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=622

Answer (score 1):

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/Implementing_HTTP_File_Up.aspx

Look into file uploads

Edit: Im assuming ASP.Net